# How to avoid duplicate insertions of "many" entity in one-to-many relationship when using a unique constraint in eclipselink/JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am working on a large codebase using Spring MVC with EclipseLink 2.5.2 on a mysql database. The database and its structure are created directly, not through any code-first approach. My problem concerns 2 tables in a one-to-many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE ROLE (
  ID BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  -- OTHER FIELDS --
);

CREATE TABLE ROLE_DOMAIN (
  ID BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  ROLE_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  DOMAIN VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  -- OTHER FIELDS --
);

ALTER TABLE ROLE_DOMAIN ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ROLE_DOMAIN_ROLE_ID FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES ROLE_BASE (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE ROLE_DOMAIN ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_ROLE_DOMAIN_ROLE_ID_DOMAIN UNIQUE (ROLE_ID, DOMAIN);
```

And in java, this is how I've got the two entities configured.

```java
@Entity
public class Role {
  private Long id;
  private Set<RoleDomain> roleDomains = new HashSet<>();

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name = "ROLE.ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ROLE.ID")
  public Long getID() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public Set<RoleDomain> getRoleDomains() {
    return roleDomains;
  }
    
  public void setRoleDomains(Set<RoleDomain> roleDomains) {
    this.roleDomains = roleDomains;
  }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE_DOMAIN")
public class RoleDomain {
  private Long id;
  private Long roleId;
  private String domain;

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name = "ROLE_DOMAIN.ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ROLE_DOMAIN.ID")
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
  public Long getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
  }

  public void setRoleId(Long roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
  }

  @Column(name = "DOMAIN", length = 255)
  public String getDomain() {
    return domain;
  }

  public void setDomain(String domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
  }
}
```

Say that in this table structure, I already have a record in ROLE and a record in ROLE_DOMAIN that references it, translating to a `Role` object named `myRole` containing the `RoleDomain` in `roleDomains`.

Now, when I add a new `RoleDomain` and save using a spring data repository like this:

```java
myRole.add(new RoleDomain("some string"));
roleRepository.save(myRole);
```

I get an exception for a duplicate insert violating my unique constraint on ROLE_ID and DOMAIN in the database.

```
[EL Warning]: 2020-10-22 14:53:22.405--UnitOfWork(994047815)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.v20190620-d6443d8be7): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '198732-some string' for key 'UQ_ROLE_DOMAIN_ROLE_ID_DOMAIN'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO ROLE_DOMAIN (ID, DOMAIN, ROLE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [27, some other string, 198732]
```

The weirdest thing about this problem is that if I remove the unique constraint from the database (Note: keeping the java annotation configuration EXACTLY the same. Literally just "DROP CONSTRAINT..." in the db) then the `save` call works just fine. It doesn't create duplicates in ROLE_DOMAIN. It does exactly what it's supposed to, just adds the new record to ROLE_DOMAIN.

I don't understand how a unique constraint in the db would cause eclipselink to act this inconsistently. Do I have something configured wrongly? Thanks.

EDIT:
I have just now tried replacing the `@Table` annotation on the `RoleDomain` class with this:

```java
@Table(name = "ROLE_DOMAIN", uniqueConstraints =
  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ROLE_ID", "DOMAIN"}))
```

It didn't change anything.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging, as EclipseLink doesn't know about the constraint and will operate the same with or without it in the database. How are you sure there are no duplicates without that constraint exactly? Your set won't show it if you've implemented your own equals method on the class incorrectly.

Comment: I know it's not inserting duplicates without the constraint because I can SELECT * FROM ROLE_DOMAIN and there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Chris after having taken a look at exactly what happens without the unique constraint, it actually is inserting all the records from the Set regardless of whether they are duplicates or not, but then it drops the duplicates from the table afterward, which is odd.

Comment: I think you may need to look closer at the timing. I would suspect you have entries in the DB, add to the set of a duplicate record  - but what is defining this to be a duplicate? The role_id and domain aren't the identifiers, so you've referenced an entirely new row, and are removing the existing one. So this isn't an update situation - why are you putting in the same data as a new entity when it already exists?

Comment: > why are you putting in the same data as a new entity when it already exists?
-----

I don't understand what you mean here. I have the Set of RoleDomains pulled from the database in the Role object. If I add a new record to it and save, I expect eclipselink to know that the other records that were already there don't have to be reinserted.

Comment: Show the SQL then, as it should not be deleting and reinserting the same entity in such a way to touch this constraint. The only way I can see this happening is if you have two different entities, and are using the same ROLE_ID and domain values within them. Two objects with two different IDs. You are 'adding' a new entity to this set and pushing one with the exact same 'data' as defined by your equals method out. Otherwise, it wouldn't do anything - no insert and no delete as nothing has changed. When you call save - do the RoleDomain all have ID values set already?

Comment: This is being used in a web context. So a user submits a change to the set of domains, we query and get the Role object in question from the db, use getRoleDomains() to get the Set of RoleDomain objects from it, add to that set, then save the Role object. That's literally the entire execution flow. I'm not copying the Role or Set. Your answer below did fix the issue though. It's now running deletes before inserts in this commit.------ EDIT: Yes they all have id values set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your constraint is that EclipseLink orders statements for batching, putting deletes last  - this is to give you a chance to clean up other constraints, to modify existing rows before rows get deleted. This can be changed so that deletes are issued first using the [setShouldPerformDeletesFirst](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_setShouldPerformDeletesFirst_Method_of_the_Unit_of_Work) method on the UnitOfWork. As this is native api, you will have to unwrap the EntityManager to get at it, using

```
em.unwrap(org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.UnitOfWork.class)
```

if you are in a transaction. This will only be set for the UnitOfWork within this EntityManager, so if you need it everywhere always, you will want to have a [session listener](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_session_event_listener.htm) with your own session adaptor class to listen for [postAcquireUnitOfWork](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/SessionEventAdapter.html#postAcquireUnitOfWork-org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.SessionEvent-) and call setShouldPerformDeletesFirst on it.

Comment: This worked, and it opened my eyes to some of the underlying mechanics of eclipselink relationship mapping and query committing, so thanks!